# Output midi events real-time in windows

Tags: python, midi

In python on windows, how do I output midi-events in real-time, so that they are heard?

There exist several libraries to parse midi files, or to write midi files. What I need is not to play a static midi file, but to generate commands on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

[python-rtmidi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-rtmidi) is a good library for this. Real-time midi in and out, works on Mac/Win/Linux platforms. The included samples are a good place to start for your purposes.